# Kivy: Click-drag Screen Visuals

Tags: python, graphics, widget, kivy, motionevent

I'm completely new to Kivy, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to even structure what I mean to make. I'd like to be able have some drawn figure on a screen (a triangle made out of 3 circles and a line drawn to connect all of them, for example) wherein I can click on a circle and drag it to another position, redrawing the line with the new position of the circle. Preferably, when dragging, I'd like the circle to "stick" with the cursor/touch input.

Would I be making each of these points Widgets? I know the graphics tools Kivy provides can draw the shapes I need, but I'm not quite sure how I'd be interacting with them again after they're drawn. Additionally, I'm not sure how I'd do the "stick" part of the drag with cursor, since it seems like Kivy would just be drawing the circle repeatedly alongside the cursor, which would result in it overlaying the figure repeatedly.

Comment: This is a pretty tough task for a first project if you're completely new to kivy. As far as the logic goes, you'd want to probably monitor the position where your mouse is clicked, then if it's within bounds from all of the drawn lines or whatnot, clear the canvas you're drawing on and move the lines +/- the deltaX and deltaY that your mouse is being dragged. Some references: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html (dragging mouse event) https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/drawing.html (drawing on a canvas)

Comment: Part of my concern is that if I clear canvas, I'd also be clearing everything I'm not touching. Are you suggesting that I redraw everything on my canvas repeatedly while dragging the point?

The other part of my issue is I'm just not sure within the architecture what a point should be. Is there some class that represents a component of a Widget that I should be inheriting from?

Thanks for your response, regardless!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to take inspiration from the Bezier example for this, as it does such manipulation for points that guide the line, and allows dragging them, much like you line would.

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/canvas/bezier.py

i also did a more complex example here 
https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/78669a514f390bf246627b190e2eba1a
which allows creation of multiple lines.

Basically, the idea, if you have multiple interaction points in a widget, is to keep track of the position of these points, in a property, and to use this property to draw the canvas, so the instructions are automatically update when the property change, and to also use the property in the `on_touch_down` method to check for distance of the touch to them, to decide which (if any) point to interact with, once this is decided, you just need to somehow link that touch to that point, so further interactions (`on_touch_move` and `on_touch_up`) with it are consistent (`touch.ud` is good for that), and to grab the touch so you don't miss any update (a parent widget can always decide this touch is actually not to propagate anymore).

code from the gist for reference (and because SO doesn't like much answers that point to external resources).

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp

KV = '''
#:import chain itertools.chain
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        text_size: self.width, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        padding: 10, 10
        text:
            '\\n'.join((
            'click to create line',
            'click near a point to drag it',
            'click near a line to create a new point in it',
            'double click a point to delete it'
            ))
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, .8
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    BezierCanvas:
<BezierLine>:
    _points: list(chain(*self.points))
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, .2
        SmoothLine:
            points: self._points or []
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            bezier: self._points or []
            width: 2
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, .5
        Point:
            points: self._points or []
            pointsize: 5
'''


def dist(a, b):
    return ((a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2) ** .5


class BezierLine(Widget):
    points = ListProperty()
    select_dist = NumericProperty(10)
    delete_dist = NumericProperty(5)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(BezierLine, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True

        max_dist = dp(self.select_dist)

        l = len(self.points)

        for i, p in enumerate(self.points):
            if dist(touch.pos, p) < max_dist:
                touch.ud['selected'] = i
                touch.grab(self)
                return True

        for i, p in enumerate(self.points[:-1]):
            if (
                dist(touch.pos, p)
                + dist(touch.pos, self.points[i + 1])
                - dist(p, self.points[i + 1])
                < max_dist
            ):
                self.points = (
                    self.points[:i + 1]
                    + [list(touch.pos)]
                    + self.points[i + 1:]
                )
                touch.ud['selected'] = i + 1
                touch.grab(self)
                return True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return super(BezierLine, self).on_touch_move(touch)
        point = touch.ud['selected']

        self.points[point] = touch.pos

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return super(BezierLine, self).on_touch_up(touch)
        touch.ungrab(self)
        i = touch.ud['selected']
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            if len(self.points) < 3:
                self.parent.remove_widget(self)
            else:
                self.points = (
                    self.points[:i] + self.points[i + 1:]
                )


class BezierCanvas(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(BezierCanvas, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True

        bezierline = BezierLine()
        bezierline.points = [(touch.pos), (touch.pos)]
        touch.ud['selected'] = 1
        touch.grab(bezierline)
        self.add_widget(bezierline)
        return True


class BezierApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        BezierApp().run()
    except:
import pudb; pudb.post_mortem()
```